# What do the elements of $k[x]/((x − λ)^n$ look like?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, modules

I want to show that ${1, [x − λ], ([x − λ])^2 , . . . , ([x − λ])^{n-1} }$ is a basis of $k[x]/((x − λ)^n$, with $λ \in k$.

**But I don't understand what $k[x]/((x − λ)^n$ is.**

**What do the elements of $k[x]/((x − λ)^n$ look like?**

**Also what does $k[X]/(x^2+2x+3)$ look like?**

Comment: $k[x]/((x-a)^n)$ is isomorphic to $k[x]/(x^n) = \{ \sum_{m=0}^{n-1} c_m x^m, c_m \in k\}$ which is a ring with the obvious addition and the multiplication generated by $x^m x^{m'} = 0$ whenever $m+m' \ge n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a canonical surjective ring homomorphism $\mathrm{pr}\colon k[x] → k[x]/(x - λ)^n$. So every element of $k[x]/(x - λ)^n$ can be written as $\operatorname{pr} (f)$ for some (non-unique) $f ∈ k[x]$.

I want to discuss the general situation. Whenever $R$ is a ring and $I$ is an ideal, there is a surjective ring homomorphism $\operatorname{pr}\colon R → R/I$ and so every element of $R/I$ can be written as $\operatorname{pr}(f)$ for some (non-unique) $f ∈ R$.

Some authors write $f + I$ for that element $\operatorname{pr}(f)$, others write $[f]_I$. Here, $f$ is a *representative* for $\operatorname{pr}(f)$.

Bottom line: They look exactly like elements of $k[x]$, except for some decoration (“$…+(x-λ)^n$” or “$[…]_{(x-λ)^n}$”) and you can calculate with them exactly as in $k[X]$ except equality holds way more often, so calculating becomes even easier.

Regarding your actual question:

*Hint*. Divide any representative $f$ of some element in $k[x]/(x-λ)^n$ with remainder by $(x-λ)^n$ to get another representative of the same element of degree less than $n$.